# shaderMaterial not work width Points

Tags: three.js

```
    function createParticles(imgData) {
        const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
        var c = 0, x = 0, y = 0, positions = [], colors = [];
        var data = imgData.data;
        x = -imgData.width * 0.5;
        y = imgData.height * 0.5;
        for (var i = 0; i < imgData.width; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < imgData.height; j++) {
                positions.push(i - imgData.width * 0.5, j - imgData.height * 0.5, 0);
            }



        }
        geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
        var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({ fragmentShader: document.getElementById('f-shader').textContent });
        return new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
    }
```

and  this is my shader:

```
 <script type="shader" id="f-shader">
    void main(){
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.58, 0.86, 1.0);
    }
</script>
```

i add this shadermaterial ,but there is nothing ,and the points will show when no material

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also need to specify a vertex shader, and the vertex shader will have to have a gl_PointSize call in it. Something like:

```
void main() {
    gl_PointSize = 10.0;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```